# Splitting Weirdly Formatted Numbers into a List

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of numbers arranged weirdly like this in a text document:

```
8 48 28 39 37 74
7 37 22 1 43 5
19 97 62 78 18 75
```

I tried to use:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
tickets = data.split(' ')
```

But it would have weird bit added to the numbers itself looking like `74\n7` and.
Is it possible to put them into a list without the weird texts in some parts?

Comment: FIles contain text, not numbers. You split at spaces - instead use `data.split()` - `'\n'` is the newline character and a whitespace as well - it is not a space hence it is not split at.

Comment: Replace your newlines with spaces `.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')`

Comment: What is weird about this? The newline char?

Comment: Is it really `74/n7` or `74\n7`?  It makes a big difference if you don't post your problem correctly

Comment: Worth noting that the code could be improved simply by invoking *line.split()* - i.e., with no arguments. You are explicitly splitting on space whereas if you don't pass any parameters it will split on all/any whitespace and therefore your newline issue will go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're seeing `/n`, but `\n`, [the escape character for a newline](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). That's because you're asking Python to read the entire file in as a single string, then split it by spaces only. However, between lines (e.g. between 74 and 7 in your example), there's a line break, not a space.

You can use `data.split()` *without any arguments* to have it split by any repeated whitespace character (i.e. spaces and newlines among other things) (see [here for the docs for `str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)):

```
with open(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.txt', 'r') as file:
    tickets = file.read().split()
```

If you want integers, cast with `int` and e.g. a list comprehension:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.txt', 'r') as file:
    tickets = [int(value) for value in file.read().split()]
```

Comment: A functional alternative to the list comprehension: `tickets = map(int, file.read().split()])`

Answer (score 0):

```
ans =[]
with open('abc.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        t = [int(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
        ans += t
print(ans)
```

This would be a way of doing it. We are reading the text and then to get rid of `\n` doing the `splitlines` call. After that, for each line, we split it to segments based on the space and then convert it to integer.